# How to make test payments on Eway in asp.net mvc project?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, payment-gateway

I started working in a project where the payment for eway is already configured in this project. I cannot figure out from the eway website on how to configure it to make test payments. 
The current settings in web.config are:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="PaymentGateway" value="2"/>
    <add key="EwayRedirectUrl" value="http://localhost:54053/#/Memberships"/>
    <add key="EwayApiKey" value="60CF3Ce97nRXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"/>
    <add key="EwayPassword" value="API-P4ss"/>
    <add key="EwayEnvironment" value="Sandbox"/>
</appSettings>
```

The following [doc](https://www.eway.com.au/_files/documentation/HostedPaymentPageDoc.pdf) in the eway website says that using this Test Credit Card: 4444333322221111 I can make dummy payments.

Am I unable to make test payments because it is a live gateway and not a test gateway? Can someone help me make test payments please?

**EDIT:**

I have some javascript code that encrypts the card and then passes to the controller. Is the problem here? Maybe the encryption isn't done properly?

```
function (card, membershipId, autoRenew) {
    var encryptCard = angular.copy(card);
    if (card !== null && !encryptCard.Token) {
        encryptCard.CardNumber = eCrypt.encryptValue(card.CardNumber, key);
        encryptCard.Cvv = eCrypt.encryptValue(card.Cvv, key);
    }

    var defer = $q.defer();

    $http.post("/Inbox/ProcessMembershipRenewPayment", parseJsonObj({ card: encryptCard, membershipId: membershipId, autoRenew:autoRenew }))
        .then(
            function(response) {
                var data = response.data;
                if (data.Status) {
                    defer.resolve(data.Message);
                } else {
                    defer.reject(data.Message);
                }
            },
            function(err) {
                defer.reject(err);
            }
        );

    return defer.promise;
}
```

I am getting some squiggly lines under 'eCrypt' saying: Use of implicitly declared variable 'eCrypt'.
In the cshtml I included the link to the js file:

```
<script src="https://secure.ewaypayments.com/scripts/eCrypt.js"></script>
```

In case encryption is not the problem, this is the method that requests payment to eway:

```
private IRapidClient _ewayClient;
private readonly string _rapidEndpoint = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EwayEnvironment"];
public void Initialize(string apiKey, string password)
{
    _ewayClient = RapidClientFactory.NewRapidClient(apiKey, password, _rapidEndpoint);
}

public EwayPaymentResponse Pay(EwayPaymentRequest request)
{
    var ewayResponse = new EwayPaymentResponse {Status = false};
    try
    {
        Transaction transaction = new Transaction
        {
            Customer = new Customer()
            {
                CardDetails = new CardDetails()
                {
                    Name = request.Customer.CardDetails.Name,
                    Number = request.Customer.CardDetails.Number,
                    ExpiryMonth = request.Customer.CardDetails.ExpiryMonth,
                    ExpiryYear = request.Customer.CardDetails.ExpiryYear,
                    CVN = request.Customer.CardDetails.CVN
                }
            },
            PaymentDetails = new PaymentDetails()
            {
                CurrencyCode = "AUD",
                TotalAmount = Convert.ToInt32(request.Payment.TotalAmount * 100)
            },
            TransactionType = TransactionTypes.Purchase,
            RedirectURL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EwayRedirectUrl"],
        };

        CreateTransactionResponse response = _ewayClient.Create(PaymentMethod.Direct, transaction);

        if (response.TransactionStatus.Status != null && (bool) response.TransactionStatus.Status)
        {
            ewayResponse.Status = true;
            return ewayResponse;
        }
        if (response.Errors != null)
        {
            foreach (var errorCode in response.Errors)
            {
                ewayResponse.ErrorMessages.Add(RapidClientFactory.UserDisplayMessage(errorCode, "EN"));
            }
            return ewayResponse;
        }

        ewayResponse.ErrorMessages.Add("Invalid credit card information.");
        return ewayResponse;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ewayResponse.ErrorMessages.Add(e.Message);

        return ewayResponse;
    }
}
```

The payment method here is direct.

Comment: Those credentials are for the public Sandbox account, so should accept any valid card number (including the 4444 one you posted). Are you getting an error?

Comment: I keep getting an error saying: "Payment cannot be processed, please check your card details." Is there a way to enable test payments? Thanks.

Comment: As I said, those credentials are for the sandbox gateway, it only accepts test payments! Can you share an access code or the URL you are entering the details into?

Comment: Please check the edit. I am still searching the project on which URL it hits. It's using an API project so I'm going through that now to check if it has any access code or URL

Comment: Also, I get these 2 responses when I send request: "Invalid encrypted card number, decryption failed","Invalid encrypted cvn, decryption failed"

Comment: You will want to make sure that the card is being encrypted (it should start with "eCrypted:") before it is sent to your server. You'll also want to make sure the key being used for encryption in the `encryptValue` function is attached to the account you are transacting with.

Comment: Yes both of those are done. In the javascript the eCrypt function is called and i put breakpoint with debugger and saw it is really being encrypted. Afterwards in the controller the api key is set to the encrypted value: _ewayClient = RapidClientFactory.NewRapidClient(apiKey, password, _rapidEndpoint);